# Check box validation code?

Tags: javascript, validation

I am experimenting with a form that has a text field and a check box. I am a designer and not a developer. I have successfully gotten the text box to Validate, but I have pasted in code for the checkbox, which for some reason either cancels out the validation or returns an error at the paypal server. Can anyone suggest a few lines of code to validate the checkbox "terms"? The textbox is called "os0"

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="myForm" onSubmit="return validateForm()" >
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="AXNKKDCZLVHM4">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Your RCEH Account Number:" />
                    Your RCEH Account Number:
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
                <td><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" />
                    Agree to <a href="../terms.html" target="new">terms and conditions</a></label>
                </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        <input type=submit value="Proceed to secure server">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x=document.forms["myForm"]["os0"].value;
        if (x==null || x==""){
            alert("RCEH account number must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: which type of validation you want to do on checkbox?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. LightStyle solved it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you only want your checkbox to be checked, below there is the code you need, and this is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NtyHc/).

```
function validateForm() {
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm"); //get the form element via ID
    if (form.os0.value == "")
    {
        alert("RCEH account number must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    if (!form.terms.checked) { // checks if the checkbox called "terms" is checked; if it is not, alerts a message and return false
        alert("Terms must be read and approved");
        return false;
    }
    return true; //if everything is okay, return true and submit the form
}
```

Comment: Light Style that worked a charm! Much appreciated! I had tried pasting a few different lines from the internet. I was confused, some posts had multiple 'var' lines. Again, much appreciated.